# What does double asterisk on file path mean in app.routes.ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a app.routes.ts file where I have an array called appRoutes. My structure for the array is this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
...
{ 
        path: 'example/:example1/:example2',
        loadChildren: () => import('./example/example.module').then(m => m.Example),
        resolve: {
            example: ExampleResolver
        },
        data: {
            title: 'Example'
        },
        canActivate: [ ValidateExample ]
},
...
{
        path: '**', redirectTo: '/home',
}
```

where the last object in the appRoutes array is

```
path: '**', redirectTo: '/home'
```

What does the double asterisk mean in this case and how does it relate to

```
redirectTo: '/home'
```

Comment: It basically means, everything else redirect to /home, so if the path doesn't match any of the defined paths that will run.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial#adding-a-404-page

Comment: Hi, please refer the official angular link for wildcard routes : 
 https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-wildcard-routes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `path` property use `wildCard` for path matching. the router take your path and try to match it with the paths registered inside the array object until it found a match. this search process could be exact search or matching with [wildCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

the `**` wild card will always return true no matter what search value you gave it to it. so if all paths return no match the one with this wild card will return true so that your application won't through an error. such path use for either showing a 404 error page or redirect to home page.

Answer (score 1):

For setting up a wild card route in Angular you use ‘**’ (double asterisk). This wild card route catches all routes that are not configured with in the route definition.

{ path: '**', component: COMPONENT_NAME}

This order of routes is important because the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) uses a first-match wins strategy. When matching [routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) if wildcard route, which matches every URL, is at the top then the component paired with wildroute will be the one always called. Follow the order of :

- List routes with a static path first.
- Empty path route (with a possible redirection).
- The wildcard route comes last.

https://angular.io/guide/router#route-order

Comment: Great remark about that the wildcard route must come last! Time Saver!